# Abort 6 issues when using memcpy()

Tags: c

I am getting Abort 6 error and I have looked it up. I don't see where in my code a strcpy() is used but possibly memcpy() could be the issue? Not sure where and why its happening but it only starting appearing when I implementing the root directory update in the code.

NOTE: I have left out dir.name and will implement later when this other issue resolves.

It prints out the print functions but seems to abort when implementing the root directory code below.

The global file is below:

```
#include "../sifs.h"
#include "md5.h"

//  CONCRETE STRUCTURES AND CONSTANTS USED THROUGHOUT THE SIFS LIBRARY.
//  DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN THIS FILE.

#define SIFS_MIN_BLOCKSIZE  1024

#define SIFS_MAX_NAME_LENGTH    32  // including the NULL byte
#define SIFS_MAX_ENTRIES    24  // for both directory and file entries

#define SIFS_UNUSED     'u'
#define SIFS_DIR        'd'
#define SIFS_FILE       'f'
#define SIFS_DATABLOCK      'b'

#define SIFS_ROOTDIR_BLOCKID    0

typedef struct {
    size_t      blocksize;
    uint32_t        nblocks;
} SIFS_VOLUME_HEADER;

typedef char        SIFS_BIT;   // SIFS_UNUSED, SIFS_DIR, ...
typedef uint32_t    SIFS_BLOCKID;

//  DEFINITION OF EACH DIRECTORY BLOCK - MUST FIT INSIDE A SINGLE BLOCK
typedef struct {
    char        name[SIFS_MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    time_t      modtime;    // time last modified <- time()

    uint32_t        nentries;
    struct {
    SIFS_BLOCKID    blockID;    // of the entry's subdirectory or file
    uint32_t    fileindex;  // into a SIFS_FILEBLOCK's filenames[]
    } entries[SIFS_MAX_ENTRIES];
} SIFS_DIRBLOCK;

//  DEFINITION OF EACH FILE BLOCK - MUST FIT INSIDE A SINGLE BLOCK
typedef struct {
    time_t      modtime;    // time first file added <- time()
    size_t      length;     // length of files' contents in bytes

    unsigned char   md5[MD5_BYTELEN];
    SIFS_BLOCKID    firstblockID;

    uint32_t        nfiles;     // n files with identical contents
    char        filenames[SIFS_MAX_ENTRIES][SIFS_MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
} SIFS_FILEBLOCK;
```

**FILE1.C**

```
#include "sifs-internal.h"

// make a new directory within an existing volume
int SIFS_mkdir(const char *volumename, const char *dirname)
{

    FILE *fp = fopen(volumename, "r+");

    if(fp != NULL){

        //read in the header information
        SIFS_VOLUME_HEADER header;
        fread(&header,sizeof header,1,fp);
        printf("%zu\n", header.blocksize);
        printf("%u", header.nblocks);

        // Check for vaidty of variables
        if (header.nblocks == 0 || header.blocksize < SIFS_MIN_BLOCKSIZE) {
            SIFS_errno    = SIFS_EINVAL;
            return 1;
        }

        //read in the bitmap information
        SIFS_BIT bitmap[header.nblocks];
        fseek(fp ,sizeof header, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&bitmap, header.nblocks,1,fp);

        for (int i = 1; i < header.nblocks; i++){
            if (bitmap[i] == SIFS_UNUSED){
                bitmap[i] = SIFS_DIR;

               // update the root directory
               char          rootblock[header.blocksize];
                SIFS_DIRBLOCK rootdir_block;

                fseek(fp, sizeof header + sizeof bitmap, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&rootdir_block, header.blocksize,1,fp);

                for (int j = 0; j < SIFS_MAX_ENTRIES; j++){
                        rootdir_block.entries[j].blockID = i;
                        rootdir_block.nentries += rootdir_block.nentries + 1;
                        break;

                }

                //write the new updated root dir into the vol
                memset(rootblock, 0, sizeof rootblock);
                memcpy(rootblock, &rootdir_block, sizeof(rootdir_block));
                fseek(fp ,sizeof header + sizeof bitmap, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(rootblock, sizeof rootblock, 1, fp);

                char          oneblock[header.blocksize];
                time_t        now;
                SIFS_DIRBLOCK dir;
                memset(&dir, 0, sizeof(dir)); // set all to zero
                memset(oneblock, 0, sizeof oneblock);


                dir.modtime = time(&now);
                dir.nentries = 0;

                //set the block to 0 and assign memory of dir into block
                memcpy(oneblock, &dir, sizeof(dir));

                //write the dir data into the volume
                fseek(fp ,sizeof header + sizeof bitmap + i * header.blocksize, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(oneblock, sizeof oneblock, 1, fp);
                //memset(oneblock, 0, sizeof oneblock);

                //Update the bitmap
                fseek(fp ,sizeof header, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(bitmap, sizeof bitmap, 1, fp);

        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    SIFS_errno  = SIFS_ENOTYET;
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: `memcpy(oneblock, &dir, sizeof(dir));` seems suspicious, but there's no way to know from the code you've shown. See [mcve].

Comment: @user3386109 I provided the structure for it, what is suspicious about it?

Comment: @user3386109 When i only had the directory file it worked so I am not sure if this is the issue. Only when I implemented the root code.

Comment: `sizeof(dir)` is the size of a `SIFS_DIRBLOCK`. The size of `oneblock`  is `header.blocksize`.  It's not clear from the code whether `one_block` is big enough to hold a `SIFS_DIRBLOCK`.

Comment: @user3386109 oneblock is of size 1024 (based on arg input on command line)

Comment: `char oneblock[header.blocksize];` reserves `header.blocksize` bytes for `oneblock` where `header.blocksize` was set by `fread(&header,sizeof header,1,fp);`

Comment: @user3386109 can You write that in an answer hard to read.